# Kubernetes's http liveness probe failed when pod under heavy load

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

Just as the title says, Kubernetes's liveness probe always fails when pod is under heavy load(500+ concurrency, 100000 request), i gave more cpu & memory resources to the pod, but it does not work.

Is there any method to handle this situation ?

Thanks!

Comment: scale up and use load balancer?

Comment: In production environment, when holiday comes, we have 40,000 concurrent requests, thus 80 pods are needed, but currently in production we use docker-compose based orchestration with only less than 10 containers  @AmiHollander

Comment: which server do you use?

Comment: tomcat, with 2 vcpu & 1G memory assigned

Comment: I am worried about that when all pods are under heavy load, k8s will restart all pods, then the service will become unavailable

Comment: Any logs you may want to provide? especially  failures after you added cpu and memory resources.

Comment: I get the following event message for the pod under heavy load:

Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.20.2.28:8080/render-web/index.html: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

It seems that the root cause is the failed readiness probe, after increasing the timeoutSeconds for readiness probe, everything works fine!

I was thought that the readiness would not be performed once the pod is ready, so interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Williams Mao issue was resolved by increasing 
`readinessProbe.timeoutSeconds`.

If an application has huge load, the default `timeoutSeconds: 1` may be not enough.
Good to read: [configure-liveness-readiness-probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing probes by "kong health" command.

```
readinessProbe:                                                                                                                                                                                            
   exec:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     command:                                                                                                                                                                                               
       - kong                                                                                                                                                                                               
       - health
```